# Finding a matrix given eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, symmetry

I am asked to construct a $4 \times 4$ symmetric matrix, with given eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I understand how to actually get $A$ as a product of $P^T, D$ and $P$, when $D$ is the diagonal matrix, and $P$ is a matrix with the eigenvectors as columns.

The problem is that there is only three given eigenvectors, along with three eigenvalues (one is repeated), so my question is, how do you construct a $4 \times 4$ matrix with three eigenvectors?

For more information here is the actual question:

Let $A$ be a symmetric $4 \times 4$ matrix with real entries whose eigenvalues
are $−1$ and $2$. If $(1, 0, 0, −1)$, $(0, 1, 1, 0)$ is a basis for the eigenspace of eigenvalue $-1$ and $(1, 0, 0, 1)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $2$, find the matrix $A$.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that they didn't say that $(1, 0, 0, 1)$ _spans_ the eigenspace with eigenvalue $2$. I think they are being sly, and omitting one eigenvector (and even trying to hide its existence as much as they can).

Comment: **Hint**: consider $\langle (1,0,0,-1), (0, 1, 1, 0) \rangle^{\perp}$.

Comment: @Arthur if so, how do I find that other eigenvector?

Comment: See my comment. You should know that eigenvectors relative to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Sorry Andreas, that notation seems beyond me, this is only first year university mathematics, so it may not have been covered.

Comment: You've done dot product (aka scalar product)?

Comment: Yes we have, and I know that if the dot product of two vectors equal 0, then they are orthogonal, but how does that relate to this situation?

Comment: I'll make it an answer. Just hold on a couple of minutes.

Comment: Done (6 minutes actually).

Comment: Note that $A=PDP^T$ is **not** the correct formula (unless $P$ is an orthogonal matrix and therefore $P^T=P^{-1}$, but this does not follow from your description of $P$), and $A=P^TDP$ is even less so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the usual dot product
$$
(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4})
\cdot 
(y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3}, y_{4})
=
x_{1} y_{1} + x_{2} y_{2} + x_{3} y_{3} + x_{4} y_{4}.
$$
Then it is easy to see that $A$ is symmetric iff for all $x, y$
$$
x A \cdot y = x \cdot y A.
$$
(just take the $x = e_{i}, y = e_{j}$, where $e_{i}$ is the vector which is all zero except for a $1$ in the $i$-th position).

Now prove that if $x$ is an eigenvector with respect to $\lambda$, $y$ is an eigenvector with respect to $\mu$, and $\lambda \ne \mu$, then $x, y$ are orthogonal:
$$
\lambda (x \cdot y)
=
(\lambda x) \cdot y
=
x A \cdot y
=
x \cdot y A
=
x \cdot (\mu y)
=
\mu (x \cdot y)
$$
and $\lambda \ne \mu$ implies $x \cdot y = 0$.

Therefore in your case the missing eigenvector $v$ relative to the eigenvalue $2$ must be orthogonal to both $(1, 0, 0, −1)$ and $(0, 1, 1, 0)$. It is easy to check that this means
$$
v = (a, b, -b, a)
=
a (1, 0, 0, 1) + b (0, 1, -1, 0),
$$
for some $a, b$.

Comment: I think I understand, so therefore the remaining eigenvector relative to eigenvalue 2, must be (0,1,-1,0), correct?

Comment: Your vector is perfectly fine, and it is probably the answer your instructors expect. But any vector of the form $a (1, 0, 0, 1) + b (0, 1, -1, 0)$, with $b \ne 0$ would do. (And thanks.)